# Make HTML content not react on search (Ctrl+F)

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my web app I have a layer with a static HTML content that displays a text.

When I do a search on a page (ctrl+F) and type some text that is contained in the layer mentioned above the text is highlighted.

Is it possible to make content not react on search at all?

Or I would remove search function from the page where my app opens if I could.

Comment: Do you really want to suppress the search functionality altogether? I mean, ordinarily the highlighted text also gets _selected_, so the user can copy it to the clipboard. Do you want to prevent that as well?

Comment: @WHITECOLOR: see my solution with preventing CTRL+F down

Comment: use Pseudoelements as suggested by Fabrizio Calderan, it's awesome.

Comment: Just a curiosity, Why you don't want ctrl + f find that text? Any specific reason or just an addition to your knowledge?? - @WHITECOLOR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only option not to reveal on search is to make that an image or an external media like Flash. It is a generic browser feature (Ctrl + F) which displays that text, if it exists on the screen will be highlighted.

Comment: And rightfully so. Every time a site tampers with my browser's UI I want to scream.

Comment: I assume the only working variant for me is to render a text on a canvas element.

Comment: Yes. But browser support you have to look for, if you are using latest ones, that should not be an issue. I still suggest the traditional image or flash as they are pretty reliable in terms of their characteristics and don't let the other blocks get affected when they are incorporated. - @WHITECOLOR

Comment: Thanks, I will consider your suggestions.

Answer (score 9):

It's tricky but you could write the text of your layer as the CSS `content` property of a layer pseudoelement. In this way the search functionality is not able to detect the text, and the text itself can't be highlighted.

e.g.

Html

```
<div id="layer" data-text="this text won't be found"></div>
```

Css

```
#layer:before {
   content: attr(data-text); 
}
```

---

Also the image solution is fine but this would require an extra request and the text couldn't be zoomable everywhere using default browser functionality. Other solution requiring Flash (or also Silverlight or Java Applets) should be avoided, especially due to the lackness of the player plugin for some platforms.

Example fiddle (with CSS `attr()`) : http://jsfiddle.net/EbTNd/

Comment: This feature is great. but for non supporting browsers, text itself will not be found.

Comment: Pseudoelements are supported everywhere, since `IE8`

Comment: True. Since `IE8` they are supported.

Comment: Thanks, but my content is dynamically generated, it can not embed it into css, and I would not want to make a dynamic css styles either =)

Comment: @WHITECOLOR this is not a problem at all: see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/EbTNd/ - Using `attr()` function the CSS is not dynamic and you could inject your text as attribute of some element

Comment: Well, I will think about the possibility of using your solution. The content is quite big, it's not a sentence it's a book pages with some sophisticated css styles for proper rendering.

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent searching in your page. It is somewhat limited but you can check if it fits.

```
window.onkeydown = function(e){
  if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 'F'.charCodeAt(0)){
    e.preventDefault();
    // Comment out this last one...
    alert('Ctrl+F');
  }
}
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ozrentk/g4wrd/

Comment: I't a dirty hack =) It won't handle all the situaltions (if the search bar already activated prior app's page load or when search is called from the menu). But thanks for suggestion -)

Comment: @WHITECOLOR: yes it is :) however, it's used a lot

Answer (score 1):

One work-around is to use the CSS content declaration to inject the text on your page.
[See answer for similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7091538/is-it-possible-to-disable-ctrl-f-of-find-in-page)

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is for the highlighted text to be the same color as the surrounding text, you can change the highlight color in many browsers. Assuming the normal text is black on white,

```
::-moz-selection {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}
::-webkit-selection {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}​
::selection {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}
```

will hide the highlight, while keeping the normal select-functionality.

See also [Changing the text selection color using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578073/changing-the-text-selection-color-using-css)

Comment: The problem is not only in highlighting the content changes its position either (I have a columned content). Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Try to render the text with SVG:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <text x="0" y="15" fill="red">I love SVG</text>
</svg>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_text.asp

Edit:
After further probing it seems that to prevent search you have to put the SVG in separate file:

```
<object height="30" width="500" data="text1.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
  <embed src="text1.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
</object>
```

Comment: Just a friendly warning: to avoid malignantly being downvoted into oblivion, remove that link.

Comment: @MrLister - I am curious to know why people here don't like W3Schools?

Comment: @NathanLee Because people seem to think that http://www.w3fools.com/ should be taken as gospel. I'm not saying that W3Schools is such a good site to learn from, but there are many sites that are as bad, or worse.

Answer (score 0):

[**Disable-CTRL-F-jQuery-plugin**](https://github.com/seangransee/Disable-CTRL-F-jQuery-plugin)

*How to use:*

Include jQuery and disableFind.js.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="disableFind.js"></script>
```

Call the `disableFind()` function on the element(s) you want to make unsearchable.

```
$('p').disableFind();               // make all paragraphs unsearchable

$('.unsearchable').disableFind();   // make all elements with "unsearchable" class unsearchable

$(body).disableFind();              // make all text on page unsearchable
```

Comment: so f.. dirty.))) and slows rendering considerably for a dynamic content. Thanks for the suggestion.