# Is it possible to disable find function on a webpage, not just CTRL + F?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to disable find function. I have a text uploded and the users shuld read the whole text without cheats, like <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>. I have already disabled <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.
But I can open the find bar frome the browser menu.

I hope someone has an idea.

Comment: My idea is to never ___ever___ do this.

Comment: turn the text into an image

Comment: @inarilo or embed it as SVG paths.

Comment: You can read the `keypress` event and stop if the key combination is pressed ...but what if the user searches by using the find option in browser menu. You can't control that.

Comment: You also need to disable clipboard, I presume...

Comment: If you disable anything with JavaScript all I need to do is disable JavaScript in my browser to get around it

Comment: @evolutionxbox if it's a text node it is searchable, I have not used SVG so maybe this is not what you mean?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17965278/6799340) is great.

Comment: @inarilo I meant actual SVG paths that looks like text.

Answer (score 6):

It's not really an answer for your question but here is something better.

Just put a span with a space in the words, that should not searchable and make the span hidden.
for example:

```
<p>"This is a te<span class="foo"> </span>st."</p>
```

and the css:

```
.foo{
    font-size:0;  
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y8g10jsr/

try to search for "test" with CTRL+F

Answer (score 2):

You can degenate image based on you text on the fly with javascript library [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/). For example if you want to transform div with id `docs` into image, your code will be

```js
$(document).ready(function(){html2canvas($('#docs'), {
  onrendered: function(canvas) {
    $('#docs').html(canvas);
  }
});});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>
<div id="docs">This script allows you to take "screenshots" of webpages or parts of it, directly on the users browser. The screenshot is based on the DOM and as such may not be 100% accurate to the real representation as it does not make an actual screenshot, but builds the screenshot based on the information available on the page.</div>
```

P.S. But user still will be able to see text if he will check html of the page

Answer (score 1):

I've just tried this as a workaround and it seems to render the text unsearchable.

```css
.overlook::after {
    content: attr(data-text);
 }
```

```html
<p class="overlook" data-text="Ctrl+F will not find this">
```

Tested in Chrome, Firefox and IE.

**edit:**

Oh I hadn't seen the comment below the question - please up vote the [original](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17965278/1238344) if you find this useful.