# Restricting search only to Iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, pdfium

Is there any way to restrict the browser's <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to search only within the contents of an `iframe`?

The problem here is that I have an `iframe` which is displaying a PDF rendered by pdfium. Now when I am trying to search using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, it also highlights the content other than the one present inside the PDF. I know this is the expected behavior of the browser, but is there any way I can search only in the `iframe`? I can develop my own search functionality instead of using the browser's, but that works very well when the content within the iframe is HTML not in case of pdfium (and also pdfjs is not an option for me).

Are there any suggestions for either restricting the search to an iframe, or searching through pdfium?

[image: Sample HTML PAGE]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17965156/make-html-content-not-react-on-search-ctrlf

Comment: @GonrasKarols, Thanks but none of this solution will work perfectly foin my case :(