# What is the CSS pseudo-class to change the background color of an element when found with the browser search?

Tags: css

What is the pseudo-class that could let me set the css background color behind goal in the illustration below? Is that something that could be customized? 
Pleace notice that I want to change the style of text found with browser search and not style of text when selected (with `::selection`).

I went through [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Pseudo-classes_and_pseudo-elements) and did not manage to find the appropriate pseudo-class.

[image: Willing to change the orange to another color]

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::selection ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the text selection color using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578073/changing-the-text-selection-color-using-css)

Comment: The selection color is not the same as the color the browser gives when you search.

Comment: ::selection works when selecting with the mouse but not with the browser search

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browser search color can not be styled with CSS unfortunately.