# Can you change the background color of highlighted words using CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

When you highlight a set of words on the Internet, the default background color would be sky blue and the default font color would be white. Is there a way to change these colors using HTML or CSS?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing the text selection color using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578073/changing-the-text-selection-color-using-css)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `::selection` selector to override the default text selection color:

```css
::selection {
  color: red;
  background: black;
}
```